# template parameter name as base class

Tags: c++, templates

I've the following types:

```
typedef unsigned int uint32;

typedef void* ptr;

struct memory_options {};

struct memory_provider {};

template <typename options>
struct memory_track {};

template <typename options>
struct no_memory_track : public memory_track<options> {};

template<typename options>
struct defrag_memory_track : public memory_track<options> {};

template<typename options>
struct full_memory_track : public memory_track<options> {};

template <typename options, typename prov, typename track>
struct memory_algorithm : public track < options > {};

int main()
{
}
```

This types used to define a custom memory manager.

The problem is the class `memory_algorithm` will inherit from another class, that class will always take a `template parameter` that represent `memory_options` class, i call it `options`. The base class may be a partial specialization from `memory_track` or a subclass from it, so in `memory_algorithm` i passed 2 template parameters one represents the class name - i.e. `track` - and the other represent the `memory_options` class - i.e. `options` - now whenever i tried to compile the code with sample test unit using GCC and Visual C++ 2008 i got the error:

for visual c++:

> missing ',' before '<'
>
> see reference to class template instantiation 'memory_algorithm' being compiled

for GCC:

> error: expected template-name before '<' token
>
> error: expected '{' before '<' token
>
> error: expected unqualified-id before '<' token

What is the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: If would be very useful to point the line(s) on which the errors happened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, what you need is probably to make `track` a *template template parameter*, rather than a regular type parameter:

```
template <typename options, typename prov, template<typename> class track> 
//                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
struct memory_algorithm : public track < options > {};
```

Comment: can you point me to location inside the c++03 standard that talk about this matter.

Comment: @Muhammadalaa: In C++03, it is Section 14.3.3. However, keep in mind the Standard is quite technical and sometimes hard to read. You may consider a book instead.